# I want the min date for a group of rows and identification of that row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have input like this:

[image: input]

I want Excel to tell me min date for o1, o2... but also give me which row has this min date.

Desired output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use below formula to mark lines with min date per group:

`=IF(B2=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$B$2:$B$13,"")),"MIN","")`

It's an array formula, so press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked for the 13 rows.. Now I have to do it to the actual sheet which has 5000 rows . I need to drag the formula to all rows right?

Comment: you also need to adapt `$A$2:$A$13` to fit your range. Or just use `A:A` and `B:B`

Comment: It worked .. The reason it is not working is the date field has time as well .. doesnt excel understand time ? 2018-11-19 13:00:00.0
13-01-2019 13:00:00.0
13-01-2019 13:00:00.0

Comment: Excel might not understand your "time" if it's formatted as text. In that case you need to convert it to proper date / time first

Answer (score 0):

To give min date for an order:
`=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$13=E2,$B$2:$B$13,""))`

To give corresponding identifier:
`=INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MATCH(E2&F2,$A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,0))`

Both are array formulas, so press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing them.

[image]

Comment: can I get it in the next column attached the  required outputin a image